# Using system.exit

Tags: python

I am trying to add a sys.exit to my code now, but I want it to display the print messages before quitting. Can I do this? Also, at the end of my code, I would like to give the user the option to quit or start again, but when they type quit after finishing the first game, it just uses quit as their name.

```
import random
import sys

def system_exit(exitCode):
    sys.exit()

# uses randrange instead of randint for better results in Python 3.7 
# randrange stops just before the upper range, use (1, 11) for 1-10

num = random.randrange(1, 11)

name = input("What is your name? Or if you would rather quit, type quit at 
any time. " "\n")


i = name
while i != "quit":
    print('Hello', name,'!')

    while i.lower() == 'quit':
        print ("Sorry, you did not select a number in the range or 
selected to quit. Good bye.")
        system_exit(4)





    your_guess = input('Enter a number between 1 and 10.' '\n')
    if (your_guess.lower() == "quit"):
        print ("Sorry, you did not select a number in the range or 
selected to quit. Good bye.") #this isn't showing up before closing
    your_guess = int(your_guess)

# display the number guessed
    print("Your number is", your_guess)

    while num != your_guess:


                if your_guess < num:
                        print("Your guess is too low.")
                        your_guess = int(input("Guess another number from 
1 to 10: " '\n'))

                elif your_guess > num:
                        print("Your guess is too high")
                        your_guess = int(input("Guess another number from 
1 to 10: " '\n'))

                else:
                    print ("Sorry, you did not select a number in the 
range or selected to quit. Good bye.") #this isn't showing up before 
closing
                    system_exit(4)

    print("The correct number was", num)





print("***************************************************************")

    name = input("What is your name? Or if you would rather quit, type 
quit. ")


    num = random.randrange(1, 11)
print("Thank you for playing!") #this isn't showing up before closing
system_exit(0)
```

Comment: You can compare a string effectively ignoring case by using `if i.lower() == 'quit':`.

Comment: Is there a reason for `system_exit` to just ignore its argument? You also never actually change the value of `i`, so there's no way for your code to exit once you are in the `while` loop.

Comment: @chepner Ignore its argument? Can you explain a bit, I am very new to coding.  Also, is there a way I can implement a way to exit while in the loop?

Comment: `system_exit` takes an `exitCode` argument, but you never use it.

Answer (score 0):

Replace the following line of code:

`your_guess = int(input('Enter a number between 1 and 10.'))`

with the code below:

```py
your_guess = input('Enter a number between 1 and 10.')
if (your_guess.lower() == 'quit'):
    #print some break message 
your_guess = int(your_guess)
```

Comment: Thank you for that. How would I get the print statement to show? Each time quit is typed, it just closes. Here is the updated file https://www.dropbox.com/s/eazbss8nbggddu4/M3Lab1mg-1.2.py?dl=0

Comment: @MatthewGalloway This is an issue with the environment in which you are running your code, not the code itself.